# AJAX PHP Database NOT WORKING no errors

Tags: php, ajax, database

I am new to AJAX and am trying to insert form data into a database using ajax and php. It is simply not working, I had errors to start off but now there are no more errors and the database doesn't update and there is no response text. Please Help!

AJAX

```
    function submit(){
        var vid = <?php echo $user['vid'] ?>;
        var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var rules = document.getElementById("rules").value;
        var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "/content/training/request/submit.php", false);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("vid="+vid+"&type="+type+"&rules="+rules+"&comments="+comments);
    }
</script>
```

PHP FILE AJAX IS CALLING:

```
<?php
require("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/config/db.php");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO trainingRequests (vid, type, rules, comments, timeSubmitted) VALUES (:vid,:type,:rules,:comments,:timeSubmitted)"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':vid', $vid);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt->bindParam(':rules', $rules);
$stmt->bindParam(':comments', $comments);
$stmt->bindParam(':timeSubmitted', $time);

$vid = $_POST["vid"];
$type = $_POST["type"];
$rules = $_POST["rules"];
$comments = $_POST["comments"];
$time = time();

$stmt->execute();

echo "Submitted!";
```

Comment: You should use `encodeURIComponent()` on the parameters that you're sending, in case they contain any special characters.

Comment: @Barmar Do you have any idea why this isn't working?? And thanks for the input

Comment: Check your Apache error log to see if the script is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an HTTP URL in `require`. When you access the PHP script through the webserver, it **runs** the script (in another server instance, so it doesn't affect the current script), it doesn't return the script contents. Change it to:

```
require("../../config/db.php");
```